# Fibonacii's algorithm in C++ - recursively

Tags: c++, algorithm, fibonacci

I have a problem with my code. There is a Fibonacci's function which I hope you know what does. And there two files: In0201.txt and Out0201.txt. As well, the programme should get the value from file "In0201.txt" and write the results to Out0201.txt.

Some value is being written but instead writing sequence of numbers ( to file ), it writes a value like it was a sum of all this numbers from sequence. Does anybody know why it happens ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Fibonacci
long double fib(int n) {
    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int tmp;

    ifstream inputFile("In0201.txt");
    if (inputFile.is_open()) {
        inputFile >> a;
        cout << "Loaded the value 'n' from file: " << endl;
        cout << a << " " << endl;
        inputFile.close();
    }

    ofstream outputFile("Out0201.txt");
    if (outputFile.is_open()) {
        tmp = fib(a);
        cout << "Fibonacci's sequence number: " << tmp << endl;
        outputFile << tmp << ", ";
        outputFile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the code in the posting, don't included a link to it.

Comment: Give an example of your input, your actual output, and your expected output. It isn't clear what the problem is from the question.

Comment: I don't get it. You tell it to write one number in the file, and you don't know why it is writing one number into it?

Comment: Works here as written, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is there is no sequence numbers of algorithm in output file.

Comment: Given input 15, I get output 610 when I run it.

Comment: When you open the file, maybe you need to put a mode on it? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/

Comment: It's not a problem, it does exactly what you tell it to do - writes Nth fib number to the file

Comment: I get 610 for input 15 too, as expected.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in answering.

Comment: If I interpret [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290081/fibonaciis-algorithm-in-c-recursively#comment18120722_13290266) correctly, you want to write the Fibonacci numbers not exceeding the value in the input file to the output file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (outputFile.is_open()) {
    tmp = fib(a);
    cout << "Fibonacci's sequence number: " << tmp << endl;
    outputFile << tmp << ", ";
    outputFile.close();
}
```

This code will output to the file a single integer number followed by a comma. If you want to output each of the return values from `fib(int n)` then you'll need to restructure your code so that the string you wish to write to file is appended inside the recursive loop.

**Solution**

```
 long double fib(int n, ofstream &openFile) {
     if(n == 0)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     if(n == 1)
     {
         openFile<<1<<", ";
         return 1;
     }
     ofstream dummyStream;
     long double nextFib = fib(n-1, openFile) + fib(n-2, dummyStream);
     openFile<< nextFib <<", ";
     return nextFib;
 }


int main()
{
    int a;

    ifstream inputFile("In0201.txt");
    if (inputFile.is_open()) {
        inputFile >> a;
        cout << "Loaded the value 'n' from file: " << endl;
        cout << a << " " << endl;
        inputFile.close();
    }

    ofstream outputFile("Out0201.txt");
    if (outputFile.is_open()) {
        outputFile << 0 << ", ";
        fib(a, outputFile);
        outputFile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of `dummyString` is to disregard half of the results since they are being duplicated by calling fib twice.

Comment: Would say more clear about changing the code ? :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what output you're looking for, without that I can't write the code to do it.

Comment: In0201.txt
400

Out0201.txt
n=400
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377

Comment: error C2660: 'fib' : function does not take 2 arguments
error C2065: 'outputFile' : undeclared identifier
error C2228: left of '.is_open' must have class/struct/union
error C2660: 'fib' : function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: Maybe you could paste the whole changed programme in here ?

Comment: Thank you so much. But, when I put "20" to the INPUT file, in OUTPUT file there are these sequences: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765,

Comment: yeah, the first 20 Fibonacci numbers. Well, I think some people count 0 as one as well. If you want that just add it onto the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a recursive function. It calculates the sum of the Fibonacci up to the number you from in0201.txt

You should change the function like this:

```
long double fib(int n, ofstream openFile) {

 if(n == 0)
 {
     openFile<<0<<", ";
     return 0;
 }

 if(n == 1)
 {
     openFile<<1<<", ";
     return 1;
 }
 openFile<< fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)<<", ";
 return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

Haven't tasted it but this is the idea.

Comment: I'm not sure that the order that the numbers will be added to the ofstream is going to be what Maciej wants. But yes, this is the _sort_ of idea that's needed.

Comment: error C2660: 'fib' : function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: Since he changed the definition to take both the number and the ofstream, you also have to change the recursive call to fib inside of fib. Aka `openFile << fib(n-1, openFile) + fib(n-2, openFile) <<", ";`

Comment: Won't this print each number too many times? It will print fib(N) at the Nth sequence and also when it's used in the recursive calls for fib(N+1) and fib(N+2).

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it. If I didn't have a problem, I wouldn't asked. Thanks to everyone who answered through my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the line `outputFile << tmp << ", ";` to

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    outputFile << fib(i) << ", ";
outputFile << fib(a) << endl;
```

If you want to list the sequence (as your question and code implied).

Comment: This should do the trick, if you want the sequence from 0 to a yes